RPGLE error "RNF3438 30 LIKE keyword is expected but not found; definition is ignored."
I am new to programming with RPGLE I was trying to write a simple code to read data from a file and displaying it in the screen. While doing it I get errors:
RNF3438 30      000600  LIKE keyword is expected for field BNBIN1 but not found;
definition is ignored.
RNF7030 30      002200  The name or indicator DSPLY is not defined.
I have tired to figure it out but I have failed to do so....
This is pracfile.pf
 A                                      UNIQUE
     A          R RQOCBN
      *
     A            BNBIN1         9B 0       TEXT('BINARY')
     A            BNBIN2         9S 2       TEXT('ZONED DECIMAL')
     A            BNBIN3         9P 2       TEXT('PACKED DECIMAL')
     A            BNBIN4         2F 2       TEXT('FLOATING POINT')
     A            BNBIN5        20A         TEXT('ALPHANUMERIC DATA')
     A            BNBIN6          L         TEXT('DATE DATA')
     A            BNBIN7          T         TEXT('TIME DATA')
     A            BNBIN8         9H         TEXT('HEXADECIMAL DATA')
     A            BNBIN9          Z         TEXT('TIMESTAMP DATA')
     A            BNBIN10        95         TEXT('BINARY CHARACTER DATA')
      *
     A          K BNBIN1

This is pracpgm.rpgle
**free

     dcl-f PRACFILE disk Usage(*input:*output:*update:*delete);

     // Declaring standalone for individual variables in a field
        dcl-s  BNBIN1    binary(9);               //binary data
        dcl-s  BNBIN2    packed(9:2);             //packed decimal data
        dcl-s  BNBIN3    zoned(9:2);              //zoned decimal data
        dcl-s  BNBIN4    float(4);                //float data
        dcl-s  BNBIN5    char(20);                //alphanumeric data
        dcl-s  BNBIN6    date;                    //date data
        dcl-s  BNBIN7    time;                    //time data
        dcl-s  BNBIN8    char(9);                 //hexadecimal data
        dcl-s  BNBIN9    timestamp;               //timestamp data
        dcl-s  BNBIN10   char(9);                 //binary character data

      // Read the database file
       read pracfile;

      // Loop till the end of file and display character read from the file
       dow not %eof
           dsply ('Binary: ' + %char(BNBIN1));
           dsply ('Packed decimal: ' + %char(BNBIN2));
           dsply ('Zoned decimal: ' + %char(BNBIN3));
           dsply ('Floating point: ' + %char(BNBIN4));
           dsply ('Character: ' + BNBIN5);
           dsply ('Date: ' + %char(BNBIN6));
           dsply ('Time: ' + %char(BNBIN7));
           dsply ('Hexadecimal: ' + BNBIN8);
           dsply ('Timestamp: ' + %char(BNBIN9));
           dsply ('Binary: ' + BNBIN10);
           read PRACFILE;
        enddo;

        *inlr = *on;                    // Last record = ON
        return;                         // End Program

I don't understand the error message completely why is LIKE keyword is expected for field BNBIN1?
dsply is a command in rpgle why is the name or indicator DSPLY is not defined?
I tried finding the solutions in internet and reading the rpgle documentations but I was unable to find the soution to the problems.

The error about DSPLY is because you are missing a ; on the dow not %eof
line.
The error about BNBIN1 is because binary is not the correct type in free-format; instead it is bindec
dcl-s  BNBIN11   bindec(9);

However, never* use BINDEC data type in RPG.
It's left over from before RPG supported actual integer data types.
The DDS binary data type is an actual integer data type.  So the 9B 0 is actually a 4 byte (aka 10 digit) integer supporting -2147483648 to 2147483647.  You'd want integer(10) in RPG.  RPG's bindec(9) only supports -999999999 to 999999999
Related note, make sure ctl-opt EXTBININT(*YES) is specified.
Secondly, you don't need to declare the stand-a-lone variables at all.  RPG pulls in the field names from the file.  This should be all you need.
**free
ctl-opt EXTBININT(*YES)
dcl-f PRACFILE disk Usage(*input:*output:*update:*delete);

// Read the database file
read pracfile;

// Loop till the end of file and display character read from the file
//  while the file name is not needed, I prefer to include it always.
dow not %eof(pracfile)
     dsply ('Binary: ' + %char(BNBIN1));
     dsply ('Packed decimal: ' + %char(BNBIN2));
     dsply ('Zoned decimal: ' + %char(BNBIN3));
     dsply ('Floating point: ' + %char(BNBIN4));
     dsply ('Character: ' + BNBIN5);
     dsply ('Date: ' + %char(BNBIN6));
     dsply ('Time: ' + %char(BNBIN7));
     dsply ('Hexadecimal: ' + BNBIN8);
     dsply ('Timestamp: ' + %char(BNBIN9));
     dsply ('Binary: ' + BNBIN10);
     read PRACFILE;
enddo;

*inlr = *on;                    // Last record = ON
return; 

*Ok almost never, if you had a PF field defined binary with decimal places, maybe RPG's BINARY would be useful.

You would have also got message RNF3308 (Keyword name is not valid). It would appear in the compiler listing immediately under the line with the dcl-s for BNBIN1.
The RPG listing can be confusing since some of the messages are listed in the source section and some of them are listed in the "Additional diagnostic messages" section after the source.
If you're using the compile listing to find your errors, I would search for RNF and first deal with any messages with severity greater than 0 that appear in the source section,

@BarbaraMorris make a good point, but I'd recommend using RDi or VSCode so that you can better see the errors in context.  I know RDi showed me both, so it was immediately obvious.  Context assist gave me the right keyword; I honestly thought binary was right.  I've never actually used BINDEC.

We named the keyword "BINDEC" (short for "binary decimal") so that people wouldn't accidentally define their integer fields as RPG's weird "binary" data type.

@BarbaraMorris makes sense, I just never noticed before. :D
